# Python Proxy Scraper / Checker adding multi-threading trouble

Tags: python, multithreading

I have managed to piece together a proxy scraper/checker, it does work but it is quite slow. I have heard that adding threading can speed up the process, this is past what I am capable of and am wondering if anyone can help show me how to implement threading into the code. I read that the threading library is included with python, I had an attempt at adding it but it seemed to create a second thread doing exactly the same, so it was just going through the same list of proxies at the same time saving duplicates. here is the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice
import threading
import time
    
stop_flag = 0
    
def get_proxies():
    link = 'https://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=displayproxies&proxytype=all&timeout=5000&country=all&anonymity=all&ssl=no'
    other = 'https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=http'
    get_list1 = requests.get(link).text
    get_list2 = requests.get(other).text
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(get_list1, 'lxml')
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(get_list2, 'lxml')
    list1 = soup1.find('body').get_text().strip()
    list2 = soup2.find('body').get_text().strip()
    mix = list1+'\n'+list2+'\n'
    raw_proxies = mix.splitlines()
    t = threading.Thread(target=check_proxy, args=(raw_proxies,))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return check_proxy(raw_proxies)

def check_proxy(proxies):
    check = 'http://icanhazip.com'       
    for line in proxies:

        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0","Accept-Encoding": "*","Connection": "keep-alive"}
        try:    
            response = requests.get(check, proxies={'http': 'http://'+line}, headers=headers, timeout=5)
            status = response.status_code

            outfile = open('good_proxies.txt', 'a')
            if status is 200:
                print('good - '+line)
                outfile.write(line+'\n')
            else:
        
                pass
        except Exception:
            print('bad  - '+line)
    outfile.close()        

get_proxies()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should run *much* faster. It is best probably to do all the file writing and printing in the main thread and have the worker threads simply return results back:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from functools import partial

stop_flag = 0

def get_list(session, url):
    get_list = session.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_list, 'lxml')
    return soup.find('body').get_text().strip()


def get_proxies(session, executor):
    link = 'https://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=displayproxies&proxytype=all&timeout=5000&country=all&anonymity=all&ssl=no'
    other = 'https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=http'
    lists = list(executor.map(partial(get_list, session), (link, other)))
    mix = lists[0] + '\n' + lists[1] + '\n'
    raw_proxies = mix.splitlines()
    with open('good_proxies.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0","Accept-Encoding": "*","Connection": "keep-alive"}
        session.headers.update(headers)
        futures = {executor.submit(partial(check_proxy, session), proxy): proxy for proxy in raw_proxies}
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            proxy = futures[future]
            is_good = future.result()
            if is_good:
                print('good -', proxy)
                outfile.write(proxy + '\n')
            else:
                print('bad -', proxy)


def check_proxy(session, proxy):
    check = 'http://icanhazip.com'
    try:
        response = session.get(check, proxies={'http': 'http://'+proxy}, timeout=5)
        status = response.status_code
        return status == 200
    except Exception:
        return False


N_THREADS=100
with requests.Session() as session:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N_THREADS) as executor:
        get_proxies(session, executor)
```

Partial output:

```
bad - 104.40.158.173:80
bad - 47.105.149.144:3128
good - 185.220.115.150:80
bad - 138.197.157.32:8080
bad - 138.197.157.32:3128
good - 116.17.102.174:3128
good - 183.238.173.226:3128
good - 119.8.44.244:8080
good - 1.174.138.125:8080
good - 116.17.102.131:3128
good - 101.133.167.140:8888
good - 118.31.225.11:8000
good - 117.131.119.116:80
good - 101.200.127.78:80
good - 1.70.67.175:9999
good - 116.196.85.150:3128
good - 1.70.64.160:9999
bad - 102.129.249.120:3128
bad - 138.68.41.90:3128
bad - 138.68.240.218:3128
good - 47.106.239.215:3328
good - 183.162.158.172:4216
bad - 138.68.240.218:8080
good - 115.219.131.244:3000
bad - 138.68.161.14:3128
good - 185.49.107.1:8080
bad - 134.209.29.120:8080
```

**Explanation**

The speed improvements are brought about primarily using threading and secondarily using a [`Session object`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=session#session-objects) provided by the `requests` package, the main advantage of which is that if you are making several requests to the same host, the same TCP connection will be reused.

Python provides two thread pooling mechanisms, (1) the undocumented `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` class, which shares the same interface as the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` class used to create a pool of sub-processes and (2) the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class from the `concurrent.futures` module, which shares the same interface as the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class from the same module, which is used for creating a processor pool. This code uses the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class.

Threads are lightweight and relatively inexpensive to create and a typical desktop computer can support several thousand. A given application, depending on what it is doing, may not profit, however, by creating more threads beyond some maximum. And threading is only suitable for "jobs" that are non-CPU intensive. That is they relinquish the CPU frequently to allow other threads to run because they are, for example, waiting for an I/O operation or a URL get request to complete. This is because Python byte code cannot run in parallel in multiple threads because the Python interpreter obtains the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) prior to executing byte code.

A `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance (assigned to variable `executor`) is created specifying the number of threads to be in the pool using the `max_workers` parameter. Here I rather arbitrarily specified 100 threads. You could try increasing this and seeing if it improves performance. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance has two methods one can use for submitting "jobs" or "tasks" to the thread pool for execution. See [concurrent.futures documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). Function `map` is similar to the builtin `map` function in that it returns an iterator that applies a function to every item of its iterable result, yielding the results. The difference is that the function calls are now going to be made concurrently by submitting each call as a "job" to the thread pool. The function that help builds the `raw_proxies` list is `get_list` and it is responsible for retrieving a single URL:

```
def get_list(session, url):
    get_list = session.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_list, 'lxml')
    return soup.find('body').get_text().strip()
```

I would now like to *concurrently* call this function for each URL, so I would like to use the `map` function where the *iterable* argument is the list of URLs. The problem is that `map` will only pass to the worker function a single argument (each element of the iterable for each call), but I also want to pass the `session` argument. I could have assigned the `session` variable to a global variable, but there was another way. `functools.partial(get_list, session)` creates another function that when called behaves as if `get_list` is being called with its first parameter "hard-coded" to be `session` and so I use this new function in the call to `map`:

```
lists = list(executor.map(partial(get_list, session), (link, other)))
```

I take the *iterable* being returned by the call to `map` and turn it into a `list` that I can later index.

The other method one can use to submit a job to a thread pool is called `submit`. It takes as arguments the worker function and the worker function's arguments and immediately returns an instance of a `Future` without waiting for the job to complete. There are various methods you can apply to this `Future` instance, the most important one is `result`, which blocks until the job has completed and returns the return value from the worker function. I could have easily used the `map` function again passing the `raw_proxies` as the iterable argument and then iterate over the return value from the call to `map`. But I would be blocking on the jobs in the order in which they were submitted (i.e. the order in which they appear in the `raw_proxies` list). And that's probably not too bad because the program will not finish until all the "jobs" have finished anyway. But it is slightly more efficient to process the results of a job as soon as it is completed independent of its submission order if you don't require outputting the results in a specific order. The `submit` function, which returns a `Future` instance, provides that flexibility:

I individually submit each proxy IP as a separate job and I store the resulting `Future` in a dictionary as the key with its value being the IP value used to create the job. I do it all with a single statement using a dictionary comprehension:

```
futures = {executor.submit(partial(check_proxy, session), proxy): proxy for proxy in raw_proxies}
```

I then use another method provided by `concurrent.futures`, `as_completed`, to iterate through all the key values of the dictionary, i.e. the Futures, to return each `Future` instance as they are completed and then query the `Future` for the job's return value, which will be either `True` or `False`:

```
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        proxy = futures[future]
        is_good = future.result()
        if is_good:
            print('good -', proxy)
            outfile.write(proxy + '\n')
        else:
            print('bad -', proxy)
```

Comment: thanks @Booboo thats great it does run really fast. can you explain what you implemented and how it works, so i can learn from it please if you dont mind.

Comment: ok, yes i will read up on the concurrent.futures module.  I just didnt think there would be that many changes to the code. thanks again for the help, ill accept the answer.

Comment: I have added an explantion.